# Lower bound on a subgroup generated by two elements $\langle a,b \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$ such that $|a|=2$ and $|b|=3$ and $a\neq b$.

It follows immediately that $G$ contains at least $4$ elements since $\langle a\rangle$ cannot be a subgroup of $\langle b \rangle$ since $2$ does not divide $3$ and $a$ cannot equal $b$ or $b^2$.

> Is there anything more that can be said about the lower bound on 
>   $|\langle a,b \rangle|$?

Could it be $5$ or even $6$?

**Edit**

I'm very sorry I forgot to mention it but in the book Lagrange's Theorem has not been mentioned. So I'm trying to do this without it.

Answer (score 6):

It *must* be at least $6$ because of a little theorem named after Joseph-Louis [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are both subgroups of $\langle a, b\rangle$, and therefore $2$ and $3$ must both divide $|\langle a, b\rangle|$.

Of course, without any more information, you cannot say any more about the size (if it is finite, it must be divisible by $6$). It might be just $6$, which is the case for instance for $\langle 2, 3\rangle \subseteq \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$. Or it could be infinite, which is the case in the group
$$
\{a, b \mid a^2 = b^3 = 1\}
$$
or it might be anything in-between.

(If you are unfamiliar with that notation, here is a short explanation: $\{a, b\}$ without any restrictions is called the *free group* generated by $a$ and $b$. Its elements are finite words using the four letters $a, b, a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, and the group operation is putting one word after the other, and then cancelling any inverses that might appear next to one another.

With the restriction $a^2 = b^3 = 1$, this means that any time you see the sub-word $aa$, you might remove it, and the same with $bbb$. Incidentally, this makes $a^{-1} = a$ and $b^{-1} = b^2$ as well, so now you can make do with only $a$ and $b$ as the letters of your words. Note that $|ab| = \infty$, which was the whole point of making this example.)

---

**Edit** Why there must be at least $6$ elements without resorting to Lagrange's theorem.

The six elements that are guaranteed to be different from one another is $e, a, b, b^2, ab, ab^2$. In general, if $\gcd(|a|, |b|) = 1$, then every element $a^ib^j$ with $0\leq i<|a|$ and $0\leq j<|b|$ will be different from every other such element. This implies that $|\langle a, b\rangle| \geq |a|\cdot |b|$. Here is why:

Assume, for contradiction, that $a^{i}b^{j} = a^{k}b^{l}$ with $0\leq i, k<|a|$ and $0\leq j, l<|b|$, and that at least one of $i \neq k$ and $j \neq l$ is true. This gives:
$$
a^ib^j = a^kb^l\\
a^{-i}a^ib^j = a^{-i}a^kb^l\\
b^j = a^{k-j}b^l\\
b^jb^{-l} = a^{k-j}b^lb^{-l}\\
b^{j-l} = a^{k-j}
$$
It's important to note that neither $a^{k-i}$ nor $b^{j-l}$ are the identity. We know that one of them is not, because of our assumption that either $i \neq k$ or $j \neq l$. Technically, this means that only one of the above is not the identity, but since we have equality, we know that it goes for both of them.

Now, raise this last equality to the power of $|a|$, and we get
$$
b^{|a|(j-l)} = a^{|a|(k-i)} =(a^{|a|})^{k-i} = e
$$
This means that $|b|$ divides $|a|(k-i)$. Since $\gcd(|a|,|b|) = 1$, we get that $|b|$ divides $k-i$. Since $k-i \neq 0$, we must have $|b|\leq |k-i|$ (absolute value signs because $k-i$ might be negative). Because of the restraints on $i$ and $k$ (they're both non-negative, and both smaller than $|a|$), we must have $|k-i| <|a|$. This gives $|b|<|a|$.

On the other hand, raising the same relation to the power of $|b|$ instead, a completely analoguous argument gives $|a|\leq |j-l| <|b|$. Thus we have our contradiction, and therefore we must have $a^ib^j \neq a^kb^l$.

Note that if we limit ourselves to $|a| = 2$ and $|b| = 3$, this proof becomes a bit shorter and more manageable: We know that $e, a, b, b^2$ are all different. The last ones to check are $ab$ and $ab^2$. In the following, $i, j = 1, 2$.

- $ab^i = e$ cannot be true since this implies $b^i = a$
- $ab^i = a$ implies $b^i = e$, which is also false
- $ab^i = b^j$ implies $a = b^{j-i}$, which is either $e, b$ or $b^2$, depending on $i$ and $j$. Either way, it's false
- Lastly, $ab = ab^2$ implies $b = b^2$, which is also false

And therefore there are at least $6$ elements in $\langle a, b\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it but in the book Lagrange's theorem hasn't been mentioned. Could you add a little something about what one can say without Lagrange's theorem? For example, without it, is $4$ the best lower bound? I'm really sorry I forgot to write it in my question.

Comment: @astudent I have added a general proof, and then a shorter proof that applies directly to your situation. Use whichever one you'd like.